# ASP.NET Core 7 openiddict-core 4 auth server returns The mandatory 'token' parameter is missing in the cloud but works locally

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, openiddict

I have 2 projects an auth server and an API, but when I try to get anything from the API, the auth server always returns

> The mandatory 'token' parameter is missing

Despite it working locally on my machine

Auth server built with openiddict core 4.6 with this configuration:

```
services.AddDbContext<AuthDbContext>(options =>
            {
                // Configure the context to use Microsoft SQL Server.
                options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
                options.UseOpenIddict();
            });

// Register the Identity services.
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
            {
                options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
            }).AddDefaultUI()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AuthDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddGoogle(options =>
            {
                IConfigurationSection googleAuthNSection =
                configuration.GetSection("Authentication:Google");
                options.ClientId = googleAuthNSection["AppId"];
                options.ClientSecret = googleAuthNSection["AppSecret"];
            })
            .AddFacebook(options =>
            {
                IConfigurationSection FBAuthNSection =
                configuration.GetSection("Authentication:Facebook");
                options.ClientId = FBAuthNSection["AppId"];
                options.ClientSecret = FBAuthNSection["AppSecret"];
            })
            .AddMicrosoftAccount(microsoftOptions =>
            {
                microsoftOptions.ClientId = configuration["Authentication:Microsoft:AppId"];
                microsoftOptions.ClientSecret = configuration["Authentication:Microsoft:AppSecret"];
            })
            .AddTwitter(twitterOptions =>
            {
                twitterOptions.ConsumerKey = configuration["Authentication:Twitter:AppId"];
                twitterOptions.ConsumerSecret = configuration["Authentication:Twitter:AppSecret"];
                twitterOptions.RetrieveUserDetails = true;
            });

// Configure Identity to use the same JWT claims as OpenIddict instead
// of the legacy WS-Federation claims it uses by default (ClaimTypes),
// which saves you from doing the mapping in your authorization controller.
services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 5;
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;

                options.ClaimsIdentity.UserNameClaimType = Claims.Name;
                options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType = Claims.Subject;
                options.ClaimsIdentity.RoleClaimType = Claims.Role;
            });

if (!environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    // OpenIddict offers native integration with Quartz.NET to perform scheduled tasks
    // (like pruning orphaned authorizations/tokens from the database) at regular intervals.
    services.AddQuartz(options =>
                {
                    options.UseMicrosoftDependencyInjectionJobFactory();
                    options.UseSimpleTypeLoader();
                    options.UseInMemoryStore();
                });

    // Register the Quartz.NET service and configure it to block shutdown until jobs are complete.
    services.AddQuartzHostedService(options =>
                {
                    options.WaitForJobsToComplete = true;
                });
            }

    services.AddOpenIddict()
              // Register the OpenIddict core components.
              .AddCore(options =>
              {
                  options.UseEntityFrameworkCore().UseDbContext<AuthDbContext>();
                  if (!environment.IsDevelopment())
                  {
                      options.UseQuartz();
                  }
              })
              // Register the OpenIddict server components.
              .AddServer(options =>
              {
                  options.SetIssuer(new Uri(configuration["OpenIddict:App:Issuer"]));

                  options.SetTokenEndpointUris("connect/token")
                  .SetLogoutEndpointUris("connect/logout")
                  .SetIntrospectionEndpointUris("connect/introspect");

                  options.AllowPasswordFlow();
                  options.AllowRefreshTokenFlow();
                  options.AllowClientCredentialsFlow();

                  options.RegisterScopes(
                      Scopes.OpenId,
                      Scopes.Email,
                      Scopes.Profile,
                      Scopes.Roles,
                      Scopes.Phone
                  );

                  options.AddEncryptionKey(new SymmetricSecurityKey(Convert.FromBase64String(configuration["OpenIddict:App:Key"])));

                  // Register the signing credentials.
                  options.AddDevelopmentSigningCertificate();

                  // Register the ASP.NET Core host and configure the ASP.NET Core-specific options.
                  options.UseAspNetCore()
                 .EnableStatusCodePagesIntegration()
                 .EnableAuthorizationEndpointPassthrough()
                 .EnableLogoutEndpointPassthrough()
                 .EnableTokenEndpointPassthrough()
                 .DisableTransportSecurityRequirement(); // During development, you can disable the HTTPS requirement.
              })
              // Register the OpenIddict validation components.
              .AddValidation(options =>
              {
                  // Import the configuration from the local OpenIddict server instance.
                  options.UseLocalServer();

                  // Register the ASP.NET Core host.
                  options.UseAspNetCore();
              });
```

The API is defined like this:

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            });

// Register the OpenIddict validation components.
services.AddOpenIddict().AddValidation(options =>
              {
                  // Note: the validation handler uses OpenID Connect discovery
                  // to retrieve the address of the introspection endpoint.
                  options.SetIssuer(Configuration["OpenIddict:App:Issuer"]);
                  //options.AddAudiences(Configuration.GetSection("OpenIddict:App:Audiences").Get<string[]>());

                  // Configure the validation handler to use introspection and register the client
                  // credentials used when communicating with the remote introspection endpoint.
                  options.UseIntrospection()
                   .SetClientId(Configuration["OpenIddict:App:ClientId"])
                   .SetClientSecret(Configuration["OpenIddict:App:ClientSecret"]);

                  options.AddEncryptionKey(new SymmetricSecurityKey(Convert.FromBase64String(Configuration["OpenIddict:App:Key"])));

                  // Register the System.Net.Http integration.
                  options.UseSystemNetHttp();

                  // Register the ASP.NET Core host.
                  options.UseAspNetCore();
              });
```

The logs from the server

```text
2023-07-31 12:40:15.261 +03:00 [INF] Starting web host
2023-07-31 12:40:15.752 +03:00 [INF] User profile is available. Using '/var/www/vhosts/example.com/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys' as key repository; keys will not be encrypted at rest.
2023-07-31 12:40:15.778 +03:00 [INF] Start installing Hangfire SQL objects...
2023-07-31 12:40:16.348 +03:00 [INF] Hangfire SQL objects installed.
2023-07-31 12:40:17.130 +03:00 [INF] Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
2023-07-31 12:40:17.132 +03:00 [INF] Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
2023-07-31 12:40:17.132 +03:00 [INF] Hosting environment: Production
2023-07-31 12:40:17.132 +03:00 [INF] Content root path: /var/www/vhosts/example.com/emsapi.example.com
2023-07-31 12:40:17.207 +03:00 [INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://emsapi.example.com/ - -
2023-07-31 12:40:17.959 +03:00 [WRN] Failed to determine the https port for redirect.
2023-07-31 12:40:17.985 +03:00 [INF] Executing ObjectResult, writing value of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ProblemDetails'.
2023-07-31 12:40:18.010 +03:00 [INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://emsapi.example.com/ - - - 404 139 application/problem+json;+charset=utf-8 803.5904ms
2023-07-31 12:40:33.656 +03:00 [INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://emsapi.example.com/api/Role - -
2023-07-31 12:40:33.708 +03:00 [INF] Start processing HTTP request GET https://emsauth.example.com/.well-known/openid-configuration
2023-07-31 12:40:33.716 +03:00 [INF] Sending HTTP request GET https://emsauth.example.com/.well-known/openid-configuration
2023-07-31 12:40:33.782 +03:00 [INF] Received HTTP response headers after 62.6108ms - 200
2023-07-31 12:40:33.787 +03:00 [INF] End processing HTTP request after 81.2677ms - 200
2023-07-31 12:40:33.793 +03:00 [INF] The configuration request was successfully sent to "https://emsauth.example.com/.well-known/openid-configuration": {}.
2023-07-31 12:40:33.826 +03:00 [INF] The configuration response returned by "https://emsauth.example.com/.well-known/openid-configuration" was successfully extracted: {
  "issuer": "https://emsauth.example.com/",
  "token_endpoint": "http://emsauth.example.com/connect/token",
  "introspection_endpoint": "http://emsauth.example.com/connect/introspect",
  "end_session_endpoint": "http://emsauth.example.com/connect/logout",
  "jwks_uri": "http://emsauth.example.com/.well-known/jwks",
  "grant_types_supported": [
    "password",
    "refresh_token",
    "client_credentials"
  ],
  "scopes_supported": [
    "openid",
    "offline_access",
    "email",
    "profile",
    "roles",
    "phone"
  ],
  "claims_supported": [
    "aud",
    "exp",
    "iat",
    "iss",
    "sub"
  ],
  "id_token_signing_alg_values_supported": [
    "RS256"
  ],
  "subject_types_supported": [
    "public"
  ],
  "token_endpoint_auth_methods_supported": [
    "client_secret_basic",
    "client_secret_post"
  ],
  "introspection_endpoint_auth_methods_supported": [
    "client_secret_basic",
    "client_secret_post"
  ],
  "claims_parameter_supported": false,
  "request_parameter_supported": false,
  "request_uri_parameter_supported": false,
  "authorization_response_iss_parameter_supported": true
}.
2023-07-31 12:40:33.840 +03:00 [INF] Start processing HTTP request GET http://emsauth.example.com/.well-known/jwks
2023-07-31 12:40:33.840 +03:00 [INF] Sending HTTP request GET http://emsauth.example.com/.well-known/jwks
2023-07-31 12:40:33.865 +03:00 [INF] Received HTTP response headers after 24.7939ms - 200
2023-07-31 12:40:33.865 +03:00 [INF] End processing HTTP request after 25.6956ms - 200
2023-07-31 12:40:33.867 +03:00 [INF] The cryptography request was successfully sent to "http://emsauth.example.com/.well-known/jwks": {}.
2023-07-31 12:40:33.870 +03:00 [INF] The cryptography response returned by "http://emsauth.example.com/.well-known/jwks" was successfully extracted: {
  "keys": [
    {
      "kid": "82505E438088042B74788D41785ED38ECAF04C53",
      "use": "sig",
      "kty": "RSA",
      "alg": "RS256",
      "e": "AQAB",
      "n": "2r86IbMsH_TcNTHENgBDLK9-jKs47yRfZhEC_wKXdb4xeNMh9suCZF9Nf1XKQqF9iP4NvOdwrt4uybFwuUVI7PMSE5H8MiRpRvgxn4pu9g4WZj8lQQVtvUw-V9lI4xEc__f0lag2Pwitq--dJZ5SYfjdl45e_-LXrk6Td17xzzkMfjBEtPx2kND_b2JSkAf9Mkk_bUqvrY5TZ7-2h6MYRKYdOkfFwhw96OXem5GeKRCMW59M38d1u5Wl6VqG9IcznPktbTnFDeuJtMNNNLHb7YRHTNnZNA6XHEDU9-56Z3EJ5PCHyPCNl08UI9gyFJr1agl-zVxokmEYVyRV5CL7Aw",
      "x5t": "glBeQ4CIBCt0eI1BeF7TjsrwTFM",
      "x5c": [
        "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"
      ]
    }
  ]
}.
2023-07-31 12:40:33.899 +03:00 [INF] Start processing HTTP request POST http://emsauth.example.com/connect/introspect
2023-07-31 12:40:33.899 +03:00 [INF] Sending HTTP request POST http://emsauth.example.com/connect/introspect
2023-07-31 12:40:33.913 +03:00 [INF] Received HTTP response headers after 13.7692ms - 400
2023-07-31 12:40:33.913 +03:00 [INF] End processing HTTP request after 14.4593ms - 400
2023-07-31 12:40:33.914 +03:00 [INF] The introspection request was successfully sent to "http://emsauth.example.com/connect/introspect": {
  "client_id": "api_service",
  "client_secret": "[redacted]",
  "token": "[redacted]",
  "token_type_hint": "access_token"
}.
2023-07-31 12:40:33.917 +03:00 [INF] The introspection response returned by "http://emsauth.example.com/connect/introspect" was successfully extracted: {
  "error": "invalid_request",
  "error_description": "The mandatory 'token' parameter is missing.",
  "error_uri": "https://documentation.openiddict.com/errors/ID2029"
}.
2023-07-31 12:40:33.920 +03:00 [INF] The introspection request was rejected by the remote authorization server: {
  "error": "invalid_request",
  "error_description": "The mandatory 'token' parameter is missing.",
  "error_uri": "https://documentation.openiddict.com/errors/ID2029"
}.
2023-07-31 12:40:33.923 +03:00 [INF] OpenIddict.Validation.AspNetCore was not authenticated. Failure message: An error occurred while authenticating the current request.
2023-07-31 12:40:33.925 +03:00 [INF] Executing endpoint 'pp.Ems.Api.Controllers.RoleController.Get (pp.Ems.Api)'
2023-07-31 12:40:34.115 +03:00 [INF] Route matched with {action = "Get", controller = "Role", page = ""}. Executing controller action with signature System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult] Get(pp.Ems.Application.UseCases.Role.Query.GetRoles.GetRoleQuery) on controller pp.Ems.Api.Controllers.RoleController (pp.Ems.Api).
2023-07-31 12:40:34.122 +03:00 [INF] Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:
DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement: Requires an authenticated user.
2023-07-31 12:40:34.123 +03:00 [INF] Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter'.
2023-07-31 12:40:34.125 +03:00 [INF] Executing ChallengeResult with authentication schemes ([]).
2023-07-31 12:40:34.135 +03:00 [INF] The response was successfully returned as a challenge response: {
  "error": "server_error",
  "error_description": "The introspection request was rejected by the remote server.",
  "error_uri": "https://documentation.openiddict.com/errors/ID2146"
}.
2023-07-31 12:40:34.135 +03:00 [INF] AuthenticationScheme: OpenIddict.Validation.AspNetCore was challenged.
2023-07-31 12:40:34.139 +03:00 [INF] Executed action pp.Ems.Api.Controllers.RoleController.Get (pp.Ems.Api) in 20.3854ms
2023-07-31 12:40:34.139 +03:00 [INF] Executed endpoint 'pp.Ems.Api.Controllers.RoleController.Get (pp.Ems.Api)'
2023-07-31 12:40:34.140 +03:00 [INF] Executing ObjectResult, writing value of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ProblemDetails'.
2023-07-31 12:40:34.144 +03:00 [INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://emsapi.example.com/api/Role - - - 500 151 application/problem+json;+charset=utf-8 488.6649ms
2023-07-31 12:40:35.526 +03:00 [INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://emsapi.example.com/api/Role - -
2023-07-31 12:40:35.548 +03:00 [INF] Start processing HTTP request POST http://emsauth.example.com/connect/introspect
2023-07-31 12:40:35.548 +03:00 [INF] Sending HTTP request POST http://emsauth.example.com/connect/introspect
2023-07-31 12:40:35.552 +03:00 [INF] Received HTTP response headers after 4.2987ms - 400
2023-07-31 12:40:35.552 +03:00 [INF] End processing HTTP request after 4.729ms - 400
2023-07-31 12:40:35.552 +03:00 [INF] The introspection request was successfully sent to "http://emsauth.example.com/connect/introspect": {
  "client_id": "api_service",
  "client_secret": "[redacted]",
  "token": "[redacted]",
  "token_type_hint": "access_token"
}.
2023-07-31 12:40:35.553 +03:00 [INF] The introspection response returned by "http://emsauth.example.com/connect/introspect" was successfully extracted: {
  "error": "invalid_request",
  "error_description": "The mandatory 'token' parameter is missing.",
  "error_uri": "https://documentation.openiddict.com/errors/ID2029"
}.
2023-07-31 12:40:35.553 +03:00 [INF] The introspection request was rejected by the remote authorization server: {
  "error": "invalid_request",
  "error_description": "The mandatory 'token' parameter is missing.",
  "error_uri": "https://documentation.openiddict.com/errors/ID2029"
}.
2023-07-31 12:40:35.553 +03:00 [INF] OpenIddict.Validation.AspNetCore was not authenticated. Failure message: An error occurred while authenticating the current request.
2023-07-31 12:40:35.554 +03:00 [INF] Executing endpoint 'pp.Ems.Api.Controllers.RoleController.Get (pp.Ems.Api)'
2023-07-31 12:40:35.599 +03:00 [INF] Route matched with {action = "Get", controller = "Role", page = ""}. Executing controller action with signature System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult] Get(pp.Ems.Application.UseCases.Role.Query.GetRoles.GetRoleQuery) on controller pp.Ems.Api.Controllers.RoleController (pp.Ems.Api).
2023-07-31 12:40:35.600 +03:00 [INF] Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:
DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement: Requires an authenticated user.
2023-07-31 12:40:35.600 +03:00 [INF] Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter'.
2023-07-31 12:40:35.600 +03:00 [INF] Executing ChallengeResult with authentication schemes ([]).
2023-07-31 12:40:35.601 +03:00 [INF] The response was successfully returned as a challenge response: {
  "error": "server_error",
  "error_description": "The introspection request was rejected by the remote server.",
  "error_uri": "https://documentation.openiddict.com/errors/ID2146"
}.
2023-07-31 12:40:35.601 +03:00 [INF] AuthenticationScheme: OpenIddict.Validation.AspNetCore was challenged.
2023-07-31 12:40:35.601 +03:00 [INF] Executed action pp.Ems.Api.Controllers.RoleController.Get (pp.Ems.Api) in 2.0566ms
2023-07-31 12:40:35.601 +03:00 [INF] Executed endpoint 'pp.Ems.Api.Controllers.RoleController.Get (pp.Ems.Api)'
2023-07-31 12:40:35.602 +03:00 [INF] Executing ObjectResult, writing value of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ProblemDetails'.
2023-07-31 12:40:35.602 +03:00 [INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://emsapi.example.com/api/Role - - - 500 151 application/problem+json;+charset=utf-8 75.4589ms
```

How I registered the app:

```
if (await manager.FindByClientIdAsync("api_service") == null)
{
    var descriptor = new OpenIddictApplicationDescriptor
                {
                    ClientId = "api_service",
                    DisplayName = "API Service",
                    ClientSecret = "6C59DC5E-682C-45BD-A1F9-9F15869905C1",
                    Permissions =
                    {
                      Permissions.Endpoints.Introspection
                    }
                };

    await manager.CreateAsync(descriptor);
}
```

Comment: Check the API's Configuration: Verify that the API's configuration (i.e., appsettings.json or environment variables) contains the correct values for ClientId and ClientSecret used in the introspection setup.

Comment: @MD.RAKIBHASAN checked them more than once finally i decided to use appsettings.json only for both local and cloud still worked locally but not in the cloud
i suspected it had something to do with my cloud infrastructure but right now i moved on to other options to get to the bottom of it